# YoutubeAPI get community comments

Tags: youtube-api

I want to get community comments on Youtube Api. I can get comments from the video, but there is no mention of the community. Please answer somebody.

Comment: There is no api for that, unfortunately. Try share here what have you researched.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.